# Manage sessions with sanctum token and uuid information in login transactions in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, token, session-cookies

I am building the frontend of an application built with Backend Laravel using React. While logging in, I have the user's Sanctum token, uuid, OTT and OTP. How can I check the user's session with this information?
Can anyone help or have a resource for this?

I am sharing my code block below. I save the baraer token received when logging in as cookies, but I know this is a wrong usage.

```
  const handleLoginConfirmSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await LoginService.postLoginConfirm(userLoginConfirm);

      console.log("response", response);

      if (response.status === 200) {
        toast.success("Login Success! ");

        const cookieName = 'token';
        const expiresInMinutes = 60;
        const expirationDate = new Date();
        expirationDate.setTime(expirationDate.getTime() + expiresInMinutes * 60 * 1000);
    

        document.cookie = `${cookieName}=${response.data.api_token}; expires=${expirationDate.toUTCString()}; path=/; secure; SameSite=Strict`;

        window.location.href = "/?fromLogin=true";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);

      if (error.response.data.message === "OTP Error") {
        toast.error("Wrong OTP! ");

      }
    }
  };
```